# Solvability of derivation Lie algebras of local finite-dimensional commutative algebras

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, lie-algebras, singularity-theory

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional local commutative algebra (with one) over a characteristic zero field $k$. Is it true that the Lie algebra $\operatorname{Der}_k(A)$ of $k$-derivations of $A$ is solvable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is NO. Consider for instance the commutative algebra $A$ having the elements $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n$ as a $k$-basis such that $a_0$ is the unity of $A$ and $a_ia_j=0$ for all $i,j=1,\ldots,n$. Then $A$ is local and it is easily seen that $\mathrm{Der}_k(A)\cong \mathfrak{gl}(n,k)$ as Lie algebras. In particular, if $n>1$ then $\mathrm{Der}_k(A)$ is not solvable.